# Can assign value to a property on property changed event?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, uiview, inotifypropertychanged

I am working in wpf - mvvm model.

I have a textbox which holds- "marketName". In xaml I am binding the property - "newmarketname"(which is defined in my viewmodel) to this textbox. Once if user enter a new market name in that text box, the "set" method of the "newmarketname" get called.

In set  method of the "newmarketname", I call the PropertyChanged event.

And the property changed handler will call a fucntion, in which I check if the market name is already existing; if "yes", I will assign string.Empty to the property "newmarketname".
So the set method of "newmarketname" again get called followed by PropertyChanged event.

But the issue is: even though the value of "newmarketname" is getting changed to empty, it is not getting reflected in the UI.

What's the issue?

Comment: It might help if you post your code

Comment: Is this PropertyChanged event one related to INotifyPropertyChanged? If yes then why are you calling the function from there(to check existing market names), why not perform that check in setter itself and then update the variable and call the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Bcoz... for all the properties in this view model...I'm calling one method...where, depending upon the property I will do something...

Comment: Try to use dependency property and PropertyChangedCallback for doing this.

Comment: Whats the difference between these two ?..i mean...DP and normal CLR property with PropertyChanged event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF will ignore PropertyChanged events that are raised while it is setting the value.  One workaround is to use a Converter (even one that just returns the raw value) and set UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus.  Another is to set IsAsync to True.

This has been fixed in .NET 4.0.  See this blog entry for more information: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/wpf-4-0-data-binding-change-great-feature/

Comment: Can u plz tell me how to use this Converter

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the underlying variable instead of the property?  That's what I always do (by mistake).

Comment: No...am changing property itself...and "on property changed" event is getting called...

HEre...the thing is, on property changed event of one property...u r changing it again...that is first from UI...and then from code level

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could set your binding mode to TwoWay, this way it will reflect both changes from the UI and code behind

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding newmarketname, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```